# How to disable a task in Grunt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

When `grunt.loadNpmTasks` is used, a grunt task is automatically available to the command line. It can be useful, but sometimes, I would like this task to be private, so it can be used whithin the Grunt file but not available to the command line.

Here is a contrived example. If I do :

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({  
        clean: {
            test: ['test'],
            release: ['release']
        },  
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');

    grunt.registerTask('build', 'Build the project.', function() {
        console.log("building project");
    });
    grunt.registerTask('release', ['clean:release', 'build']);

};
```

... I can use the following command :

```
$ grunt release
```

However, this one is also available, and both `clean:release` and `clean:test` will be executed:

```
$ grunt clean
```

I do not want that. I want to control what can be called from the command line, since I may not have foreseen some undesirable effects if the user directly calls some tasks or subtasks.

I thought about registering a new `clean` task to supersedes the main one, and then choose what to call when `clean` is invoked (or to call nothing at all), but it does not work well since it cannot call the original `clean` task:

<strike>`grunt.registerTask('clean', ['clean:release']);`</strike>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`grunt.task.renameTask`](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.renametask)

```
var ticks = +new Date();
var clean = 'clean-' + ticks;

grunt.task.renameTask('clean', clean);
grunt.registerTask('release', [clean + ':release', 'build']);
grunt.config.set(clean, grunt.config.get('clean'));
```

Copying the configuration over is important if you want to preserve the `target`s configuration